# #include 'mysql/mysql.h' file not found - Eclipse / Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, c, eclipse, macos

I am trying to develop a c program on my Mac using Eclipse, but struggling on the most basic task of including mysql.h

Here is my code for completeness sake:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <mysql.h>

int main(void) {

  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I have tried numerous methods:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include "mysql.h"
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include "mysql/mysql.h"
```

however I always get the message when compiling "'mysql/mysql.h' file not found"

In the include I have even tried the following, to reference the file directly:

```
#include = "/usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/include/mysql.h"
```

No matter what I try to do, the message is always "'mysql/mysql.h' file not found"

Here is the GCC C Compiler script:

```
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I/usr/local/
-I/usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/include
-I/usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64
-I/usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64
-I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-osx10.8-x86_64/include 
-I/usr/local/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-osx10.8-x86_64
-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/TestConsole2.d"
-MT"src/TestConsole2.d" -o "src/TestConsole2.o" "../src/TestConsole2.c"

../src/TestConsole2.c:14:10: fatal error: 'mysql/mysql.h' file not found
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

The mysql.h can be found at /usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/include/mysql.h on my system

Just a note to add... I am extending a current c program that is on a Centos 6 server, my intentions are to build the modules on my Mac in Eclipse, test them, then integrate the modules into the program on the server.

Thank you

Comment: Just to add further, I've restarted Eclipse and now receiving a different message:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_mysql_get_client_info", referenced from:
      _main in TestConsole2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

In the source:

```
#include <mysql.h>
```

To call gcc:

```
gcc -I /usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/include ./src/TestConsole2.c
```

Comment: Just to add further, I've restarted Eclipse and now receiving a different message: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"_mysql_get_client_info", referenced from: _main in TestConsole2.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and tried

```
g++ -I/usr/local/mysql/include -o  test test-1.cpp -lmysqlclient
```

and

```
g++ -I/usr/local/mysql/include -o  test test-1.cpp -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient
```

but neither worked out, and finally it came up to me that the header may not be included in system PATH, so I added a link in *\usr\include* with

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/mysql/include mysql
```

and rebuilt with

```
g++  -o  test test-1.cpp -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient
```

and this time it worked .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First step is to verify at where are install  mysql
you can using the commands

```
ls
```

for see the file list of directory
and using

```
cd
```

in my example, the installation are in directory:

```
/usr/local/mysql-<version_my_mysql>/include/
```

second step is indicate the directory everytime compiller:

```
gcc my_program_code_file.c -I /usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/include/ -o my_program_executable
```

in code, the includers are:

```
#include <mysql.h>
```